# Bash move file to wildcard destination

Tags: bash, grep

I have some `.zip` files in the same directory as directories with similar names as the `.zip` files. I am trying to move the `.zip` files into their corresponding directory by using some sort of wildcard.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash    
find "/Volumes/volume1/test/" -type f -name "*.zip" -print0 |
  while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' FILE; do
  ZIP="${FILE%.*}"
  echo $ZIP
  MATCH=${ZIP::${#ZIP}/3+${#ZIP}/2}
  echo ${MATCH##*/}
  mv "$FILE" "$(ls -l|grep "^d.*${MATCH##*/}")"
done
```

But `grep` has a problem with the whitespace contained within `$MATCH`. I have no idea how else I would move a file to a directory with a wildcard in the destination name.

Example dir:

`drwxrwxrwx  1 username  staff       264 Jul 10 22:43 [test]Peter Jackson - This is a test dir[29.06.17][1080]{username}`

Example `.zip`

`-rw-rw-rw-  1 username  staff  13956939 Jul 10 22:58 [test]Peter Jackson - This is a test dir[29.06.17][Hi-Res].zip`

Comment: I don't understand your code. Can you show us an example of the file and directory names you're working with?

Comment: `ls | grep` is innately error-prone; see [Why you shouldn't parse the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Comment: (and `-d $'\0'` arguably misleads readers about how bash does string parsing -- it generates **exactly** the same string as `-d ''`.

Comment: What do you expect `match` to be? For your sample data I'm getting `declare -- match="[test]Peter Jackson - This is a test dir[29.06.1"`, and that doesn't look like what you're likely to actually **want**.

Comment: You said the directories have "similar" names. Define *similar*.

Comment: @melpomene No, since the last few chars differ from the zip file and the dir.

Comment: Also, note that all-caps names are used for variables with meaning to the shell and operating system, whereas variables with lowercase letters in their names are guaranteed safe for application use. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html, paragraph 4.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy This is what I want, since `[test]Peter Jackson - This is a test dir[29.06.1*` will match the dir `[test]Peter Jackson - This is a test dir[29.06.17][1080]{username}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
  zip="${file%.*}"
  match=${zip::${#zip}/3+${#zip}/2}
  candidate_dirs=( "$match"*/ )
  if ! [[ -d "${candidate_dirs[0]}" ]]; then
    echo "No candidate directories (starting with $match) found" >&2
  elif (( ${#candidate_dirs[@]} != 1 )); then
    echo "Exactly one candidate directory must exist; found ${#candidate_dirs[@]}" >&2
  else
    # emit a correctly escaped, eval-able command. Remove the printf '%q ' to actually mv
    printf '%q ' mv -- "$file" "${candidate_dirs[0]}" && printf '\n'
  fi
done < <(find "/Volumes/volume1/test/" -type f -name "*.zip" -print0)
```

Note:

- We're moving the `while` loop into the main shell and putting the `find` command in a process substitution to avoid the issue described in [BashFAQ #24](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024).
- We're using a glob expression ending in `/` to force our glob to match only directories; storing the results of that expression in an array; and checking that array's length.
- Because a glob expands to itself if no matches exist (if `nullglob` or another flag modifying the shell's behavior doesn't exist), we're also testing whether the first entry in the array of results actually exists.

Comment: This is perfect - does exactly what it should. Thanks a bunch, also for the explanation!